# linux fedora NetworkManager dbus freedesk configuration

Tags: linux

The /var/log/message file is flooded with NetworkManager freedesktop error messages. I have several questions:
1. What is causing these messages. 
2. There seems to be a NetworkManager freedesktop relationship. Where are the config files for this. 
Thanks, Dan

Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Mar 24 08:27:02 computer NetworkManager[25856]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own: (4) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

Answer (score 0):

As for the freedesktop errors, those are actually NetworkManager dbus errors, NetworkManager API just happens to be prefixed by `org.freedesktop` as NetworkManager is at least partially a `freedesktop.org` project.

As for the errors, you would have to track down the reason using the logs and a bit of experimentation. There may be a serious problem in your system. Information provided in your question is insanely insufficient. At the very least your question lacks information about the system, NetworkManager, the application trying to interface it and reproducibility and circumstances of the issue.

Comment: The system is fedora 20. The errors appear to be related to: NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax, NetworkManager.network-control, NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan, NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax, and NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi, I have looked through the NetworkManager config and do not see the configuration for these services.